# Datastudio: Blended Data: Date aggregation not working

Tags: looker-studio

I have a blended data source, that connects two filtered Google Analytics metrics. In there I have a calculated chart field, that gives me the ratio between these two filtered metrics. Now I'm trying to change the date aggregation to year-month, but there seems to be a problem.

This is with date auto, which is perfect:

[image]

However this is what happens with Year Month aggregation:

[image]

There should be only a line per month left, but somehow the aggregation is not working.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this? I've setup my blended data source at least 10 times trying to use the date on one source or as a key, but none worked.

Cheers
Andreas

Comment: I wonder if you ever figured this out? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: @JoppeDeCuyper: Unfortunately no. There doesn't seem to be a solution to this for now.

Comment: I didn't find a fix either. Worked around it by making a custom field with the function `MONTH(date)` and using that. Works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

> I didn't find a fix either. Worked around it by making a custom field with the function **MONTH(date)** and using that. Works like a charm

Your solution did the job perfectly. Thank you, Joppe. I am quoting your workaround as an answer to bring more visibility to it.

**Credit**: [Joppe De Cuyper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1582522/joppe-de-cuyper) (comment in the question)

Comment: I had a very similar issue with blended data aggregated to weeks. Following this same logic I added a new custom field with `WEEK(date_field)` to the data source and used this as join keys for the blending. Data Studio recognises the custom field as „compatibility mode“ date format, but for now it works well.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution here :
https://support.google.com/looker-studio/thread/96504295?hl=en

I have found others with a similar issue

https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/65220021?hl=en

The workaround I guess is to maybe have dedicated column that represents date month in your source data. So 01-01-2021 for all Jan 2021, etc. As long as they are the same it should work I think.

WORKAROUND

You can use the following Formula and add a calculated field to your source table:

DATE(YEAR(your_date_column),MONTH(your_date_column),1)
Last edited Feb 3, 2021

Answer (score 0):

I tried DATE(YEAR(your_date_column),MONTH(your_date_column),1) and it worked but I wanted to get also rid of "1" string from the month format (for example 1 Jan 2023) and only show Jan 2023.

So I tried MONTH(your_date_column) and it returned a good result.

[custom date month field formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpfkV.png)